# How to keep parent and child items sequentially indexed if Tree is collapsed or expanded?

Tags: angularjs

Are there any ways to keep items in ng-repeat based tree in sequential number order if Item has child Items collapsed/expanded or not?

I'm meaning something like this:

Expanded state

```
Parent1                 (index value should be 0)
 -----  Child 1         (index value should be 1)
 -----  Child 2         (index value should be 2)
Parent 2                (index value should be 3)
Parent 3                (index value should be 4)
 ----   Child 1         (index value should be 5)
Parent 4                (index value should be 6)
 -----  Child 1         (index value should be 7)
 -----  Child 2         (index value should be 8)
 -----  Child 3         (index value should be 9)
 -----  Child 4         (index value should be 10)

same data when collapsed

Parent1                 (index value should be 0)
Parent 2                (index value should be 3)
Parent 3                (index value should be 4)
Parent 4                (index value should be 6)
 -----  Child 1         (index value should be 7)
 -----  Child 2         (index value should be 8)
 -----  Child 3         (index value should be 9)
 -----  Child 4         (index value should be 10)
```

Best Regards,

Comment: The indices have not changed when you collapsed the items, they are just hidden, are they not? The array of nodes are still 0-10, so they should be available for whatever you wish to do, and simply show the items or not.  What code did you use to build the tree? Can you share your source?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have used two ng-repeats and when collapsed parent item's is collapsed then it's childs are hiddening and $index has changed. That cause the problem. When collapsing, $index is different than it is when all items are expanded. So, should I use some kind of calculation for $index when parent item is collapsed or what? Real thing is that indexing is changing when parent is collapsed. Seems to be so that collapsed child items does not have sequential $index numbering then. But when all items are expaded $index values for all items seems to be all rigth.

Answer (score 0):

Data Structure in this case is Tree like following:

```
parentTree = [];
parentTree[0].childs = [];
```

So, ng-repeat should handle three. Is it possible?

How to iterate Tree with ng-repeat?

So ng-repeat should handle ng-repeat="parent in parentTree" and
if parent.childs > 0 then ng-repeat="child in parent"

How to implement this?